# Is atmospheric correction relevant for Landsat Level2 before classification?

Tags: landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I am quite new in the field of remote sensing.
I would like to do a separate classification of two Landsat 8 Level2 images and then do a LULCC change detection.
For the pre-processing steps, it is recommended to correct radiometric/atmospheric.

I plan to convert from DN to ground reflectance (or radiance) using atmospheric models (e.g. the i.toar tool from Grass GIS). I have doubts about the relevance of this correction as I am using a Landsat
8 Level 2 image.

Is it mandatory to do this conversion for a L2 image before starting the classification?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to ask one question (note that "recommendation" requests are often the cause of closure as being *opinion-based*).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from [Landsat Collection 2 Level-2 Science Products](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/landsat-collection-2-level-2-science-products), the level 2 Landsat 8 products are already corrected for radiometric, geometric and atmospheric effects. So to answer your question, no you do not.

If you are not satisfied with the atmospheric correction and you want to apply your own then you need to start from the Level 1C product.